# SSHd performs actions based on username

Tags: ssh

My web host uses an elegant way of handling multiple sites while keeping each one self-contained. For me to login via `ssh`, I use the following:

```
ssh hostname -l username1_sitename1
```

This does something along the lines of chroot-ing me to the particular directory related to `sitename1` and changing my UID to match. Same for if I used `ssh hostname -l username1_sitename2`, etc. The login for `username1` uses the same password each time and the `hostname` remains constant.

If another user, `username2`, were to need access to `sitename1` then they can access said site using a similar scheme:

```
ssh hostname -l username2_sitename1
```

and they would be given the same UID as `username1` receives when accessing `sitename1`.

I wish to replicate a similar scheme on one of my computers. Is it possible to achieve this without manually adding each incarnation of `username_sitename` to the system?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Thousands of perl scripts, son!

Long answer:
Once you get into the large hosting game, you want everything to be done via scripting, and all your backend processes to talk to one another.  Manual intervention means you lose.  You want one click access to suspend, create, delete, etc.  So, it's most likely not "manually" created, but someone on their side got an idea of how they want to implement things, and then wrote the necessary code to add these names to all the appropriate places, set up the permissions, etc.  As most things with hosting like this, it can be done, you just need to implement it according to your specific desires.

Comment: Along with the scripts, I would also use something like urpmi or jailkit for creating a custom jail with only specific utilities for user groups or in your case according to the sitename.